# 位置情報付きjsonデータのヒートマップによる可視化失敗

Tags: javascript, leaflet

flickrから集めた写真に関するジオタグなどの情報をクローリングして、jsonファイルにしたものを、ヒートマップで可視化する試みをしています。jsonファイルについては

```
{"bbox":[135.559,34.8749,135.8788,35.3212],"search":"kyoto","data":[
{"id":"4281151592","owner":"31676563@N05","secret":"d5a48deb7e","server":"2801","farm":3,"title":"Runner","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0,"dateupload":"1263712135","datetaken":"2010-01-17 13:17:14","datetakengranularity":"0","datetakenunknown":0,"ownername":"Teruhide Tomori","tags":["sports","japan","women","kyoto","running","京都","日本","nippon","runner","関西","ekiden","近畿","42195km","女子駅伝"],"latitude":"35.039483","longitude":"135.756855","accuracy":"15","context":0,"place_id":"vAd3SUZTUb5ktGbw","woeid":"2345871","geo_is_family":0,"geo_is_friend":0,"geo_is_contact":0,"geo_is_public":1,"url_sq":"https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2801/4281151592_d5a48deb7e_s.jpg","height_sq":75,"width_sq":75,"url_m":"https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2801/4281151592_d5a48deb7e.jpg","height_m":"333","width_m":"500","url_z":"https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2801/4281151592_d5a48deb7e_z.jpg","height_z":426,"width_z":"640","hit":["kyoto"],"area":0},
{"id":"4281207666","owner":"31676563@N05","secret":"9db15de6a9","server":"2790","farm":3,"title":"A runner","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0,"dateupload":"1263714441","datetaken":"2010-01-17 13:14:16","datetakengranularity":"0","datetakenunknown":0,"ownername":"Teruhide Tomori","tags":["sports","japan","women","kyoto","running","京都","日本","nippon","runner","関西","ekiden","近畿","42195km","女子駅伝"],"latitude":"35.039483","longitude":"135.757005","accuracy":"15","context":0,"place_id":"vAd3SUZTUb5ktGbw","woeid":"2345871","geo_is_family":0,"geo_is_friend":0,"geo_is_contact":0,"geo_is_public":1,"url_sq":"https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2790/4281207666_9db15de6a9_s.jpg","height_sq":75,"width_sq":75,"url_m":"https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2790/4281207666_9db15de6a9.jpg","height_m":"500","width_m":"333","url_z":"https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2790/4281207666_9db15de6a9_z.jpg","height_z":"640","width_z":427,"hit":["kyoto"],"area":0},
{}]}
```

といった形となっています。

ヒートマップについてはleafletと、Leaflet.heat(https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat) を利用しています。

htmlファイルを開き、ファイルを選択して可視化させようとしたところ、コンソールには

```
data_array Object { d_array: Array[735] }
```

と出ておりヒートマップの描画に失敗しました。
heatLayerの引数には[[34.8749,135.559,0.5]]のような緯度、経度、ヒートマップの重み付けデータが入ります。その部分を今回はjsonデータ内のデータからもってきて、用意した配列に格納し引数として渡すという狙いでした。

以下コードです。よろしくお願いします。

```
    document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', function (evt) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var src = {
            max:45,
            data:[]
        };
        var data_array = {
            d_array:[]
            };
        var dataset = JSON.parse(e.target.result);
        var east = Math.max(dataset.bbox[0],dataset.bbox[2]);
        var west = Math.min(dataset.bbox[0],dataset.bbox[2]);
        var north  = Math.max(dataset.bbox[1],dataset.bbox[3]);
        var south  = Math.min(dataset.bbox[1],dataset.bbox[3]);
        var cells = 50;
        var grid = {};
        document.getElementById("tag").innerHTML = "Search: "+dataset.search;
        var range = Math.min(north - south, east - west) / cells;
        dataset.data.forEach(function(item){
            if(item.latitude && item.longitude) {
                var lat = parseFloat(item.latitude);
                var lng = parseFloat(item.latitude);
                var weight = item.ispublic;
                var sn = Math.floor((lat - south) / range);
                var we = Math.floor((lng - west) / range);
                if(grid[sn+"."+we]) {
                    grid[sn+"."+we]++;
                } else {
                    grid[sn+"."+we]=1;
                }
                var da = {
                    lat:lat,
                    lng:lng,
                    weight:weight
                };
                var d = {
                    lat:lat,
                    lng:lng,
                    count: 1
                };
                src.data.push(d);
                data_array.d_array.push(da);
            }
        });
        console.log("L.heatLayer: ", L.heatLayer);
        var heatmap = L.heatLayer(data_array,{
                    radius: range,
                    blur: 10,
                    maxZoom: 18,
                }).addTo(map);
        map.fitBounds([
            [dataset.bbox[1],dataset.bbox[0]],
            [dataset.bbox[3], dataset.bbox[2]]
        ]);
    };
    reader.readAsText(evt.target.files[0]);
});
```

Comment: よく分かりませんが `L.heatLayer(...).addTo(map);` の`map` は、`function (evt) {...}`の中で存在していないのでは？

Comment: `json`を読ませた所でエラーが出たわけですから、その`json`もぜひ質問に記載して下さい。もちろん全部載せる必要はありまん。一要素のダミーとかで十分です。もちろん、そのダミーで同じ問題が起きなければ駄目ですが、もしダミーで問題が起きないならば、エラーの原因が`json`ファイルにあると分かるのですから、一歩前進となります。

Comment: エラーが解消されたようで、よかったですね。ヒートマップの描画が出来無いという事ですが、`L.heatLayer`に渡している`data_array`は意図どおり作成されていますか？ `console.log("data_array: ", data_array);`などとして、確かめて見てるのもよいのではないでしょうか。
`

Comment: Object { d_array: Array[735] }となってるので、意図通りになってませんでした・・・。元々data_arrayの部分には[[32.22,135,65,0.5]]のような緯度経度ヒートマップの重みづけデータの三つが配列として入るのですが、自分の場合はそれがたくさんあるため、jsonを読み込んで、配列を作ってjsonから緯度経度などのデータを配列に渡してそれをheatLayerの引数として渡したかったのですが・・・。

Comment: 一度にチャレンジしている事が多すぎるかもしれません。私としては、とりあえず目標を最低二つには分割した方がよいと感じます。 「`L.heatLayer`に配列(とりあえずダミーでよい)を渡し目的のヒートマップを作成出来る事を確認する」「`json`データを目的の形式の配列に変換する」それぞれ、別の関数として切り出し、開発・テストするのがよいです。

Comment: そうですね・・・。段階を踏んでやってみます。
まず、「L.heatLayerに配列を渡して、ヒートマップが作成できることを確認する」についてですが、data_arrayに緯度と経度をいくつか入れて実行してみたところ、ちゃんとヒートマップが描けていました。（どうやら重み付けは必須ではなかったようです。）次の「jsonデータを目的の形式の配列に変換する」についてはこれから取り組んでみます。
丁寧にありがとうございます

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しましたので、報告します。
ヒートマップの描画に失敗していた件ですが、L.heatLayerの第1引数であるdata_arrayをdata_array.d_arrayとすることで描画できました。よく考えたら、配列の要素を追加するpushではdata_array.d_array.pushってしてるし描画の際の配列の参照もそれに従ってないとだめなのかなと思いました。（正しい理解なのか今も不安ですが・・・）